# execvp() permission denied and string concat problem

Tags: c, string, exec

I am writing a shell and need to run external commands. Concatenation/string copy for string is extremely problematic which i have no clue why. Below is my problem:

```
void extern_com(char* buffer){
    int i = 0, j = 1, k = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    char *args[5];
    char temp[MAX_CMD_BUFFER];
    args[0] = "/bin/";
    args[4] = NULL;
    while(buffer[i] != '\0'){
        temp[k] = buffer[i];
        printf("%c\n", buffer[i]);
        if(buffer[i] == '\n'){
            temp[k] = '\0';
            char temp_arg[k+1];
            k = 0;
            while(temp[k] != '\0'){
                temp_arg[k]=temp[k];
                k++;
            }
            temp_arg[k]='\0';
            args[j] = temp_arg;
            break;
        }
        if(buffer[i] == ' '){
            temp[k] = '\0';
            char *temp_arg = malloc(k+1);
            k = 0;
            while(temp[k] != '\0'){
                temp_arg[k]=temp[k];
                k++;
            }
            temp_arg[k]='\0';
            args[j] = temp_arg;
            j+=1;
            k = 0;
            i+=1;
            free(temp_arg);
            continue;
        }
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    if(j < 3){
        j+=1;
        for(j = j; j<4; j++){args[j] = NULL;}
    }
//args[1] here is correctly my input which is ls
    int len0 = strlen(args[0]), len1 = strlen(args[1]), len=len0+len1;
    char* t=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_CMD_BUFFER); //however args[1] somehow mutates into some other random string here
    strcpy(t, args[1]); //which prevents me from writing the path correctly
    char path[len+1];
    for(i = 0; i<len0; i++){
        path[i] = args[0][i];
        printf("args[1]: %c",args[1][i]);
    }
    for (i = len0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        path[i] = t[i-len0];
    }
    path[strlen(path)] = '\0';
    printf("path: %s\n", path);
    pid = fork();
    if(pid==0) {               //fork child
            execvp(path, args);
            perror("exec");
        } else {                    //Parent
            wait(NULL);
        }
}
```

So the contatenation of strings to create the path for some reason mutates the arg[0] without me doing anything to it.

Thank you

Comment: And what are you actually passing to `execvp`? Print out all elements of `args` to see what exactly you pass.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: By the way, I never see the code change `args[0]` from pointing to `"/bin/"`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's kinda why I have no clue where to go as even without mutation args[1] it does get mutated so path ends up being /bin//b which is not /bin/ls

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. And since you're using an `exec` function you're on a system where the compilers have *sanitizers*. Build with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and be ready to get some errors when running.

Comment: I will try that thank you, i will learn how to read the debugger

Answer (score 0):

There are two main problems here.  First is this:

```
args[0] = "/bin/";
```

Since this is also what you're passing as the first argument to `execv`, you're saying that you want to run the command "/bin/".  This is a directory, and directories aren't executable (at least not in the sense that files are) hence the permission denied error.

You want to start `j` at 0 instead of 1 so "ls" gets put at `argv[0]` as the name of the command.

Second, you're declaring this inside of two blocks:

```
char temp_arg[k+1];
```

You then assign `temp_arg` to one of the elements of `args` and then exit the block.  This memory is now past its lifetime and attempting to subsequently reference it will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

You'll need to dynamically allocate this memory so it outlives the block:

```
char *temp_arg = malloc(k+1);
```

Comment: I did do that thank you and I am trying to save args[0] args[1] as path to put into the execvp however the strcopy mutates arg[1] which is ls using agr[0] and I don't know why